# submitting form using ajax with multiple submit buttons in jquery and upload file using the same

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

How can I submit my form using ajax with multiple submit buttons each with their own unique value? Everything I try just ends up with submit's value being undefined. And I also want to upload a file using the same form but I am getting 403 (FORBIDDEN) error and whenever I try to print my file using console it prints --->  FormData {}   <---- What does that mean. Is my FormData() variable is storing NULL. Any help would be great!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#compile").click(function(){ 
    $("#formid").submit('function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();    //stop stuff happening
        event.preventDefault(); //Stop from submitting the form normally
        console.log($(this).serialize());
  
        var doc = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        console.log(doc);

        var $form = $( this ),
        code = $form.find("input[name='user_code']").val(),
        lang = $form.find("input[name='language']").val(),
        csrf = $form.find("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
        var request = $.ajax({    //create an ajax call
        //var $form =$(this),
        type : $(this).attr('method'),
        url : $(this).attr('action'),
        data : {user_code : code,language : lang,flag : "compile",doc : doc,csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf},     //get the form data
          processData : false,
          enctype : 'multipart/folr-data',
        dataType : "text"
     //   success : function(data){alert(data);}
    });
    request.done(function(msg){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg; 
    });
    request.fail(function() { alert("fail")});
    });
  });
  $("#save").click(function(){ 
    $("#formid").submit('function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();    //stop stuff happening
        event.preventDefault(); //Stop from submitting the form normally
        console.log($(this).serialize());
  
        var doc = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        console.log(doc);

        var $form = $( this ),
        code = $form.find("input[name='user_code']").val(),
        lang = $form.find("input[name='language']").val(),
        csrf = $form.find("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
        var request = $.ajax({    //create an ajax call
        //var $form =$(this),
        type : $(this).attr('method'),
        url : $(this).attr('action'),
        data : {user_code : code,language : lang,flag : "save",doc : doc,csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf},     //get the form data
          processData : false,
          enctype : 'multipart/folr-data',
        dataType : "text"
     //   success : function(data){alert(data);}
    });
    request.done(function(msg){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg; 
    });
    request.fail(function() { alert("fail")});
    });
  });
 $("#submit").click(function(){ 
    $("#formid").submit('function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();    //stop stuff happening
        event.preventDefault(); //Stop from submitting the form normally
        console.log($(this).serialize());
  
        var doc = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        console.log(doc);

        var $form = $( this ),
        code = $form.find("input[name='user_code']").val(),
        lang = $form.find("input[name='language']").val(),
        csrf = $form.find("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
        var request = $.ajax({    //create an ajax call
        //var $form =$(this),
        type : $(this).attr('method'),
        url : $(this).attr('action'),
        data : {user_code : code,language : lang,flag : "submit",doc : doc,csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf},     //get the form data
          processData : false,
          enctype : 'multipart/folr-data',
        dataType : "text"
     //   success : function(data){alert(data);}
    });
    request.done(function(msg){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=msg; 
    });
    request.fail(function() { alert("fail")});
    });
  });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{question.id}}. {{question.question_name}}
    <br>
    {{question.question_text}}

    <form action="result" id="formid" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="textarea" name="user_code"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="language" value="c" checked="yes">c
      <input type="radio" name="language" value="c++">c++<br>
      <input type="file" name="doc" id="doc"> 
      <input id = "save" type="submit" name="flag" value="save">
      <input id ="compile" type="submit" name="flag" value="compile">
      <input id = "submit" type="submit" name="flag" value="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
    <a href="/questionlist">Back To questions</a>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <p id = "demo"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using django as my web framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't have multiple submit buttons on the same page, you're going to have a bad time doing it that way. Simply turn them into buttons, since you are not actually submitting the form the normal way.

### Your HTML can look like this:

```
  <body>
    <form action="result" id="formid" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="input" name="user_name"><br>
      <input type="textarea" name="user_code"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="language" value="c" checked="yes">c
      <input type="radio" name="language" value="c++">c++<br>
      <input type="file" name="doc" id="doc"> 
      <div>
        <input id ="save" type="button" name="flag" value="save">
        <input id ="compile" type="button" name="flag" value="compile">
        <input id ="submit" type="button" name="flag" value="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Then for your javascript, you really need to separate the ajax call out of all those click events, and just refer to it as a function. It will be easier to maintain down the line. Here is a quick example to get you going in the right direction. I am not sure exactly what you want, since all your 3 buttons seem to do the same thing at this point. Also, this ajax submit will handle files as well as regular inputs, so you don't have to worry about separating that logic if that is what you were worried about.

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var function = ajaxSubmitForm(button,form,type){
      var code = form.find("input[name='user_code']").val(),
          lang = form.find("input[name='language']").val(),
          csrf = form.find("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
          formAction = form.attr('action'),
          formData = new FormData(form[0]);

          //I have no idea why you have three buttons executing the same submit
          //But my guess is you want to submit different items with different buttons
          //You can build that logic here if youw ant
          if(type === 'secret') {
            formData.append('username', 'JamesBond');
          } else if (type === 'buttonData') {
            formData.append('data', button.data('some-data-attribute'));
          }

          return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: formAction,
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                timeout: 20000
            });
    }

    $("#compile").on('click', function(){
      var button = $(this),
          type = $(button).data('type'),
          form = $(button).closest('form'),
          submitRequest = ajaxSubmitForm(button,form,type);

          submitRequest.done(function(){
            console.log("all done...");
          }).fail(function(){
            console.log("Something went wrong...");
          });
    });

    $("#save").on('click', function(){
      var button = $(this),
          type = $(button).data('type'),
          form = $(button).closest('form'),
          submitRequest = ajaxSubmitForm(button,form,type);

          submitRequest.done(function(){
            console.log("all done...");
          }).fail(function(){
            console.log("Something went wrong...");
          });
    });

    $("#submit").on('click', function(){
      var button = $(this),
          type = $(button).data('type'),
          form = $(button).closest('form'),
          submitRequest = ajaxSubmitForm(button,form,type);

          submitRequest.done(function(){
            console.log("all done...");
          }).fail(function(){
            console.log("Something went wrong...");
          });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank You very much Amir .  What I am doing in my javascript code is sending the same set of data along with  the value of my button.  So if the user clicks compile the data will be processed differently then when the user clicks submit or save.

Comment: Now I will be able to submit project on time

Comment: @Michaels if my answer helped you please accept as approved answer.

Comment: What changes must be made in the submit function if I have to return the html page if the user clicks on the submit button and I also want to pass a string to that page.  I need urgent help!